# Can't create a DataFrame in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to get familiar with spark by look at some of [their examples](http://spark.apache.org/examples.html) and [getting started tutorials](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html).  I want to load a text file that contains two columns of numbers seperated by a tab and then create a dataframe from that.  I was hoping to do it using the commands below:

```
>>> data = sc.textFile("amazon.txt")
>>> df = data.map(lambda r: [int(x) for x in r.split("\t")])
>>> df = df.toDF()
```

But when I execute the last command it throws the error:

```
u'Unable to locate hive jars to connect to metastore. Please set spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars.'
```

full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File "/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 57, in toDF
    return sparkSession.createDataFrame(self, schema, sampleRatio)   File "/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 526, in createDataFrame
    jdf = self._jsparkSession.applySchemaToPythonRDD(jrdd.rdd(), schema.json())   File "/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__   File "/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 79, in deco
    raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace) pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u'Unable to locate hive jars to connect to metastore. Please set spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars.'
```

based on the erorr message it looks like I need to set something called `spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars`, but I don't know what this is or where I would set it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get this issue resolved so I can create a data frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using spark version 1.5 or later then there is a possibility you may have multiple or wrong version of `spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars`

You can add below setting to $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark_defaults.conf

spark.sql.hive.metastore.version X.X.X

spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars maven

If you set spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars to maven then the appropriate jars will be downloaded and added to the classpath. You can also set it like a normal Java classpath like /usr/hive/lib/*:/usr/hadoop/lib/*

Hope this helps.

Comment: what value should I have for `X.X.X`?  I tried the version of spark I am using `2.0.1` which is the version of Spark that I am using, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: That will be your Hive version. Something like 0.14.0